# What is the bottom of a directed-complete partial order of groups?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lattice-theory

Given a directed-complete partial order of finitely presented groups, I want to say that the free group is the bottom, but I don't think that is right.

> Can anyone say what is a typical bottom in a directed-complete partial order of groups?  Furthermore, are the finitely presentable groups the finite or compact elements?

Comment: You should probably clarify what you mean by a typical dcpo of groups. Otherwise the bottom can be anything you want: just take the dcpo {G}...

Comment: Also, signatures (and greetings) aren't really necessary on MO. A signature is automatically attached to your posts.

Comment: What does "dcpo" mean?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_partial_order

Comment: Okay, take any dcpo of groups with a free group as an element and at least one other element related to the free group either by subgroup or inclusion.  I am trying to decide if free groups end up as maximal or minimal.

Comment: The order relation in the dcpo is usually defined by subgroup and I think free groups have no subgroups with added axioms (ie, added relations)...I guess I'm lost.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, subgroups of free groups are free, so if you have a minimal element lying below a free group then the minimum will be free.  (I think I must be misunderstanding the question . . . I wouldn't expect there to be a minimum most of the time.)

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the Nielsen--Schreier Theorem, which asserts that any subgroup of a free group is free?

Comment: Subgroups of free groups are free, but a free group can be the subgroup of a non-free group.  Thus, the free groups have to be at the top and free is kind of maximal.  Freeness is maximal, not minimal.  Is that a good statement?

Comment: Well, it's maximal if you think that a subgroup is greater than the group... which seems like an odd convention.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused.  Do you say $G < H$ if $G$ is a subgroup of $H$?
Or if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$?  If it is the former then everything less than a free group will be free.  If it is the latter then you can definitely have other interesting things that are less than a free group.

Comment: Is the Largeness order not a dcpo (search for `the concept of largeness in group theory'; bascially $H\leq G$ if there exists a finite-index subgroup of G which maps onto a finite-index subgroup of H, and the kernel is finite)? Here free groups (and groups with a finite index subgroup which map onto free groups) sit at the top, while the trivial group lies at the bottom.

Comment: @SeanLawton your change to the title has **actually made it incorrect.** One should speak of a DCPO of groups, not of "DCPO groups". Moreover, why not insert the definite or indefinite article before the word "bottom" if you feel these changes are **so necessary as to warrant bumping this question**?

Comment: Moreover, there seems to me to be **no semantic rationale** for putting one of the questions in blockquote format and the other one not. This is not just gratuitous editing, it is **incosistent editing**. I have rolled back to Ben Sprott's original.

Comment: @YemonChoi Why not just further improve it?

Comment: @YemonChoi Regardless, thank you for the good suggestions.  They certainly do make the question better.  I made your suggested edits.